# Changing color point in Dygraph depending on the value of another set

Tags: dygraphs

I'm trying to represent temperature values from a solar panel to heat water with an electrical resistance. I have a three column data set, first is date & time, second the temperature and third an 0 or 1 depending if the electrical resistance is connected or not.
I want to represent it changing points colors to red when the resistance is connected.
Something like this.

[Graphic with Temperatures](http://cine.no-ip.info/Grafica_Temperatura.png)

Is there any way to make this in dygraph?

I can generate another csv file with the times the electrical resistance is activated, if it is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want `drawPointCallback`. Take a look at http://dygraphs.com/tests/custom-circles.html

Comment: Yes, it's a god start point. Do you know where to find more information about the drawPointCallback function? I've searched in the API page in Documentation but it doesn't appear there.
Thanks!

Comment: You'll find the docs for it in the options reference: http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawPointCallback

Answer (score 0):

At last, I didn't find the correct way to use drawPointCallback for, depending the value of the second serie (status of the resistence), change the color/figure of the 1st serie's point (temperature value) so I decided to change mi thinking way and modify the data in the second serie to show None in case of 0 and the same value of the temperature in case of 1. In this way, and assigning a greater point size and a color to the second series it shows over the first, so I get the result I needed. http://cine.no-ip.info/Temperatura.html
I suppose there are other options to make something similar that I wanted. If not, it would be good to try to implement it.
Thanks for your help